# FitBit integration with Alexa; Play music when waking up

Tags: bluetooth, alexa, fitbit

I m trying to integrate my Fitbit with my Amazon Echo. My goal is to make my Echo play music when I wake up in the morning. Is it possible to send a notification (or alert) via Bluetooth to my phone or Echo directly from my phone at the moment I wake up?

I then want to instruct Alexa to play music upon receiving this signal from Fitbit. Can anyone tell me a best place to start? I have researched a lot but could not find a way to get data from Fitbit at the moment I wake up? Is this possible?

(I came up with an idea to connect the Fitbit to a gateway like a Raspberry Pi and use the gateway to instruct the Echo. But I got stuck at connecting Raspberry Pi to Fitbit and sending a notification from Fitbit to the gateway.)